# DIV overlaping IE hiding another DIV

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've built this website www.brownieboo.co.uk and for some reason in IE6, 7 and 8 the DIV #container is overlapping (I think) the #footer DIV and making it not visable.

Tried all sorts to fix this but haven't had much luck.

Can anyone spot what I can do in the CSS code to #container or #footer to make footer sit below #container.

Here's how it looks in IE:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

```
#footer{
height:20px;
}
```

IE 6/7 expand the footer to include all the divs inside it. so the white text get the white background from the footer.